# UISearchBar and resignFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, first-responder

I have a very basic UITableView with an attached UISearchBar, and here's the flow of what happens

UITableView is empty, user taps UISearchBar, and brings up keyboard.
Once the user taps the Search button

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar { 
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder]; //move the keyboard out of the way
    //Code....  
}
```

Works just fine, and moves the keyboard out of the way, and populates the UITableView.
The problem is any subsequent search attempts.

The same steps as before occur, however the keyboard is never dismissed.  I have a feeling something else is becoming the responder, I just need a little clarity to understand what is actually occurring.

Answer (score 31):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to guess. However, if you include:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

all views will resign first responder.

Comment: I've had similar issues with UICollectionView cells containing UITextFields and this solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: Not work in `func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)` protocol

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect but did work for my case. Will not work without **dispatch_after**

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (!searchText.length) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        });   
    }
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self performSearchWithString:searchBar.text];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```